# custom IBodyDeserializer for soap, how to I get Nancy to use it

Tags: nancy

I have written a custom IBodyDeserializer for soap messages so that I can remove the soap envelope before model binding.

What I cannot figure out is how to make it be used instead of the XmlBodyDeserializer (which it will inherit from)?

I have tried things like this in my ApplicationStartup method in bootstrapper:

container.Register(new SoapBodyDeserializer());

But it still uses the XmlBodyDeserializer and ignores by soap one.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a local copy of the nancy code to debug this, I dont really know when but if I inherit from XmlBodyDeserializer and overide Deserialize it just ignores my custom Deserialize method and calls the base class so I just cloned it

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrapper you can override `BodyDeserializers` to only return your type like `protected override IEnumerable<Type> BodyDeserializers => new[]{typeof(SoapBodyDeserializer)}`